# How do I add basic channel with a custom dialog to my Nao/Pepper app

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

This question is about Nao/Pepper robot development:

Is it possible to use basic channel with a custom dialog in my app? I 
currently have a dialog with some voice commands and want to enable basic channel too.

Comment: Which platform? Which language? We don't know anything about your app.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dialog as a collaborative. This way the default app (named `dialog_runner_dev`) from the basic channel will run also your dialog in parallel with the other dialogs.

If you use choregraphe - double click on the `your_dialog_name.dlg` file and then make sure `Add to the package conctent as collaborative dialog` checkbox is checked. After that package and install the project.